# Is there an easy way to pull windows user environment variables into Oracle SQL to use for a password entry?

Tags: oracle, plsql, environment-variables

I am looking at the idea of using my OS's Environment Variable to be used as a source for Oracle to pull as password from in a SQL query.

```
ACCEPT TeamPassword PROMPT 'Enter your team password: ';
```

I want to replace this code with something that will be able to define TeamPassword = {lookup variable from windows user variables in environment variables menu}. This code as written requires a prompt, which I am trying to get rid of, and can easily be used with via &TeamPassword. I want to be able to use the new version of this code in a similar fashion.

Anyone have any clever ideas on how to make this work?

Comment: The whole idea of a "team password" seems deeply flawed. Everyone in the team knows the password?

Comment: It's a team schema. We share a user (2 of us) for a shared userspace. It's not anything sensative. We are only aggregating data from other sources to answer business questions. I didn't set it up this way.

Answer (score 2):

This is a good example of "just because you *can* doesn't mean you *should*". Using an environment variable to hold a password is a ***VERY BAD*** idea from a security perspective. Environment variables can be audited, logged, and viewed with system monitoring tools, exposing the password for anyone to see. You don't want the password to appear in the command line for sqlplus or whatever application you are running for the same reason. This is most likely why your code has a prompt in it now - so that the password can be entered without being logged by anyone/anything else.

You would be better off using an Oracle Wallet (aka Secure Password Store) to hold your credentials. I've written a blog post about doing that here: https://pmdba.wordpress.com/2014/10/16/database-account-password-storage/, and there are plenty of other resources available with a quick Google search.

With a wallet in use you can login with no username and password (they're both stored in the wallet) and no prompt. Put the wallet in the individual user profile and in your sqlnet.ora file use an environment variable to point the wallet, like this:

```
WALLET_LOCATION=
  (SOURCE=
    (METHOD=file)
    (METHOD_DATA=
       (DIRECTORY="%USERPROFILE%\oracle\wallet")
    )
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try a wrapper script as either of the below ;

```
set TeamPassword = %1
echo %TeamPassword%
REM and then continue your script for connecting to database using the above variable
```

or

```
set TeamPassword = %env.variable%
echo %TeamPassword%
REM and then continue your script for connecting to database using the above variable
```